# What is the order of these binary trees?

Tags: co.combinatorics, noncommutative-algebra, free-lie-algebras, hall-algebras

In the book "Free Lie algebras" by the author Christophe Reutenauer, Example 4.2 (in subsection 4.1) gives the trees of degree $\le 5$ of a Hall set in magma $M(A)$, where $A=\{a,b\}$ as the following image

[image: these trees are ordered from left to right and line after line]

Could someone tell me what order is used here and any other order relation defined on binary trees?
Thank you so much for your help.